Getting Returned expression type {providers: EnvironmentProviders[]} is not assignable to type Provider[] when returning function
I was trying to create this function passing a nonce and a GtagId.  But I get a Returned expression type {providers: EnvironmentProviders[]} is not assignable to type Provider[] error in my IntelliJ.  I then tried changing Provider[] type to EnvironmentProviders[] but then get these error messages:
Assigned expression type (nonce: any, gtagId: any) => EnvironmentProviders[] is not assignable to type (nonce: any, gtagId: any) => Provider[] 
Returned expression type {providers: EnvironmentProviders[]} is not assignable to type EnvironmentProviders[] 

My code where I am getting the error:
let googleAnalyticsProviders = (): Provider[] => [];

if (Configuration.getEnvironment() !== 'development') {
   ...
   googleAnalyticsProviders = (nonce, tag): Provider[] => {
     return {
       ...
     }
   }
}

     googleAnalyticsProviders = (nonce, gtagId): Provider[] => {
            return {
              providers: [
                provideGoogleAnalytics(gtagId, { nonce } as IGoogleAnalyticsOptions),
                provideGoogleAnalyticsRouter()
              ]
            };
          };

The function will be called here:
export const appConfig = (nonce: string | null, gtagId: string): ApplicationConfig => {
  return {
    providers: [
      ...googleAnalyticsProviders(nonce, gtagId),
....

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Change ...googleAnalyticsProviders(nonce, gtagId),  to ...googleAnalyticsProviders(nonce, gtagId).providers,

Thanks but that returned 'unresolved variable' error.

You can have the function for googleAnalyticsProviders to return an array, which is of type EnvironmentProviders[].
export const Configuration = {
  getEnvironment: () => 'development',
};

export const googleAnalyticsProviders = (
  nonce: string | null,
  gtagId: string
): EnvironmentProviders[] =>
  Configuration.getEnvironment() !== 'development'
    ? [
        provideGoogleAnalytics(gtagId, { nonce } as IGoogleAnalyticsOptions),
        provideGoogleAnalyticsRouter(),
      ]
    : [];

export const appConfig = (
  nonce: string | null,
  gtagId: string
): ApplicationConfig => {
  return {
    providers: [...googleAnalyticsProviders(nonce, gtagId)],
  };
};

bootstrapApplication(App, appConfig('test', 'qerty'));

Full Code:
import {
  ApplicationConfig,
  Component,
  Provider,
  EnvironmentProviders,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  IGoogleAnalyticsOptions,
  provideGoogleAnalytics,
  provideGoogleAnalyticsRouter,
} from '@hakimio/ngx-google-analytics';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
          Learn more about Angular
        </a>
      `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}
export const Configuration = {
  getEnvironment: () => 'development',
};

export const googleAnalyticsProviders = (
  nonce: string | null,
  gtagId: string
): EnvironmentProviders[] =>
  Configuration.getEnvironment() !== 'development'
    ? [
        provideGoogleAnalytics(gtagId, { nonce } as IGoogleAnalyticsOptions),
        provideGoogleAnalyticsRouter(),
      ]
    : [];

export const appConfig = (
  nonce: string | null,
  gtagId: string
): ApplicationConfig => {
  return {
    providers: [...googleAnalyticsProviders(nonce, gtagId)],
  };
};

bootstrapApplication(App, appConfig('test', 'qerty'));

Stackblitz Demo

export seems to not getting allowed inside the if statement.   I need the function inside the if statement because I want to only get GA stuff only if its not in development.  If I remove the export const, I get 'Assigned expression type (nonce: (string | null), gtagId: string) => EnvironmentProviders[] is not assignable to type (nonce: any, gtagId: any) => Provider[] '

@ray805 updated my answer

@ray805 why are u removing export const?

Thank you!  That worked.   I removed originally export const because it was inside the if statement and compiler was saying it was not appropriate there.

You should create a custom type and assign it as the method return type.
export interface GAProvider {
providers:EnvironmentProviders[];
}

Then change the method return type as GAProvider
googleAnalyticsProviders = (nonce, gtagId): GAProvider  => {
        return {
          providers: [
            provideGoogleAnalytics(gtagId, { nonce } as IGoogleAnalyticsOptions),
            provideGoogleAnalyticsRouter()
          ]
        };
      };


Thanks the error went away.   I also changed my initialization like this(sorry forgot to include it originally in the post).  let googleAnalyticsProviders = (nonce, gtagId): GAProvider => [];  but getting an error there 'Returned expression type any[] is not assignable to type GAProvider '

You should return a valid type from that method. In this case, it is expecting a value of type GAProvider.

Can you clarify?   I am returning a GAProvider[].
